# Enabling maven dependency management disables refactor menu item in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

Does anyone notice that after enabling Maven dependency management in Eclipse for a project, the refactor item on the context menu of Java editor disappears for that project?

Is there a solution to that? A patch or upgrade? Or a kludge?

**Further Info**:
Need to further assert that the context menu on project/package explorer is unaffected. The refactor item is still there.

It is the Java Editor that is affected - where the refactor item disappeared from the context menu.

**Error Log**:

```
Plug-in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu' is invalid): org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenameProjectAction

An exception stack trace is not available.

Session data:
eclipse.buildId=2.3.3.201007151000-M2
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product com.springsource.sts.ide
```

**error log of failed action when attempting to enable GWT**:

```
Failed to update action com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.actions.AddResourcesToClientBundleAction

Exception trace:
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.jdt.model.PlatformJavaModelUtilities$IAnnotationNotAvailableException
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.clientbundle.ClientBundleResource.isProbableClientBundleResource(ClientBundleResource.java:105)
at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.clientbundle.ui.AddResourcesToClientBundleAction.selectionChanged(AddResourcesToClientBundleAction.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.refreshEnablement(PluginAction.java:206)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:277)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectActionContributor$1.run(ObjectActionContributor.java:157)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectActionContributor.contributeObjectActions(ObjectActionContributor.java:160)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectActionContributorManager.contributeObjectActions(ObjectActionContributorManager.java:97)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.addObjectActions(PopupMenuExtender.java:262)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.menuAboutToShow(PopupMenuExtender.java:339)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.fireAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:465)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:241)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1282)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1263)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu._setVisible(Menu.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPopups(Display.java:3593)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3168)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Comment: I edited the question to include an error log.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what I'm experiencing. Below a screenshot showing the **Refactoring** entry in the contextual menu of a **Maven Project**:

[alt text http://a.yfrog.com/img842/3705/screenshot008b.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img842/3705/screenshot008b.png)

And the **Refactoring** entry in the contextual menu of a Java Resource of this **Maven Project** (that I also get when right clicking in the Java editor):

[alt text http://a.yfrog.com/img201/9843/screenshot009n.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img201/9843/screenshot009n.png)

But note that I'm not using Eclipse and m2eclipse like you are, I create Maven projects outside Eclipse and **Import... > Existing Maven Projects** (I'm not fan of wizards). Not sure this makes a difference though.

Comment: Look like image have some issue?

Comment: @Pascal Thivent the images have gone

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to swallow answering my own question, but ...

The answer is: To obtain a maven managed project in Eclipse, do not use m2eclipse menu to create or enable as Maven dependency managed project. Those m2eclipse menu items are are broken.

You have to use `mvn archetype:generate` commands at the shell/command window to create that project.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
 -DgroupId=holy.moly \
 -DartifactId=holymoly \
 -Dpackage=holy.moly \
 -Dversion=1.0-VOILA
```

And then in Eclipse use the `import:maven:existing maven project` menu item to import that project into Eclipse.

Some products give their respective advisory on how to generate a maven project from shell/command window, and then to be imported into Eclipse. For example, Vaadin's:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean \
-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST \
-DgroupId=holy.moly  \
-DartifactId=holymoly \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-Dpackaging=war
```

However, attempting to enable GWT would cause error.

**Using IAM**:
I am editing to say that I uninstalled m2eclipse from one of my helios setup and installed IAM. IAM did not cause any menu items to disappear. I was able to enable GWT.

The refactor item was still on the menu but attempting to refactor on Java Editor or rename a file on Project explorer would fail:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.run_aroundBody1$advice(RenameJavaElementAction.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.run(RenameJavaElementAction.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.doRun(RenameJavaElementAction.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.run(RenameJavaElementAction.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RenameAction.run(RenameAction.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3552)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```